# High availability of http service

Tags: http, high-availability

I know this has been discussed many times. I read a lot about the subject.
Let's say I want to have a failover between http services (a static web server, a load-balancer..)

From what I understand, the only real options to me are:

- anycast
- virtual IP address (with a failover script)

I am a small shop, so I can't afford the first, and the second is difficult across various data centers.

There is also the option of using multiple A records. This would be perfect if consumers (like browsers, proxies..) would handle it well.

I think Internet should be easy to use, even if you want a high availability setup. In this case, just multiple A records make sense to me.

My question is: where can I lobby to make the HTTP protocol write this as a rule. Where can I PR it.
I'm sure there is already some discussions about it, and would be happy if you can point to some of it. (I searched without much success)

(Started from a discussion [here](http://blog.zorinaq.com/release-of-hablog-and-new-design/) )

Comment: SRV records are also interesting! https://www.pantz.org/software/bind/srvdnsrecords.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at who made the HTTP2 standard http://ietf.org/. Speak with the guys there. They have chat, discussion groups, etc.

Even though I disagree with your opinion, thank you for taking time to improve standards!

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you disagree?

Comment: I think that delivery protocols do not need to have HA built in them by default and they should leave that on the standard implementation level.